# How to filter output of "SHOW BINLOG EVENTS"

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binary-log

Without talking about master/slave replication, I just want to customize which entries I see when querying the MySQL Binary-Logs with `SHOW BINLOG EVENTS`. Already tried to find the same information in `information_schema` and `performance_schema` so that I can `SELECT` on a proper table but I was unable to find it.

The available filters [from the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-binlog-events.html) do not seem to allow this directly.

What I'd like is something like:

```sql
-- /!\ invalid syntax  /!\ --
SHOW BINLOG EVENTS WHERE Event_type = 'Query' AND Info LIKE 'UPDATE%'
```

```sql
-- /!\ invalid syntax  /!\ --
SHOW BINLOG EVENTS IN (SELECT Log_name FROM (SHOW BINARY LOGS))
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

My current workaround with the `mysqlbinlog` utility (runs in [MySQL Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)):

```sh
cd /var/lib/mysql && while read p; do mysqlbinlog -d example_db -s /var/lib/mysql/$p | grep UPDATE; done <./mysql-bin.index; cd - > /dev/null
```